# How do you duplicate a value to the next row in a specific column in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

So I have this PBI report, and I have this base column here:

[image: column 1]

I decided to split this column into two using a custom column with this code: (Column 3 is just an int column)

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "Column1", each if [#"Column3"] > 0 then [Base Column] else null)
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Column2", each if [#"Column3"] <= 0 then [Base Column] else null)
```

The resulting Column 1 and 2 looked like this:

[image: column 1 and 2]

Everything looked fine until I plotted them in a line chart, which left a gap:
[image]

I realized I had to insert the 279.8258333 value on Column 1 as well to make it look connected.

I've tried different Table.InsertRow but I can't seem to find anything on just a specific cell in a table ( the adjacent cell of the first value in Column 2). Basically I need the Column1 and 2 to have the 279 value.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do in M  / Powerquery

**Using user interface, method 1:**

Add column .. index column ...

Add column .. custom column ... with column name **Custom** and formula

```
=try #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Column1] otherwise null
```

That will grab the value from the prior row in Column1

Add column .. custom column ... with column name **NewColumn1** and formula

```
= if [Column1] = null and [Custom]<>null then [Column2] else [Column1]
```

Right click and remove Column1, Index and Custom columns

Click NewColumn1 and hit F2 and rename column to be Column1

done

**Manual code method 2**

(The three rows to create an offset column work faster on larger data sets then using an index to refer to prior row)

Create a new column that offsets Column1 down by one.  When column 1 is a null and the new column has a number, copy the value from Column2

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
// offset Column1 down by a row into new column
    shiftedList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN(Source[Column1],1),
    custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Source) & {shiftedList},
    custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(Source) & {"Previous Row"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(custom2, "Custom", each if [Column1]=null and [Previous Row]<>null then [Column2] else [Column1]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1", "Previous Row"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom", "Column1"}})
in  #"Renamed Columns"
```

**Manual code method 3**

(The three rows to create an offset column work faster on larger data sets then using an index to refer to prior row)

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
// offset Column1 down by a row into new column
    shiftedList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN(Source[Column1],1),
    custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Source) & {shiftedList},
    custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(Source) & {"Previous Row"}),
 #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(custom2,  each [Column1],  each if [Previous Row]<>null and [Column1]=null  then [Column2] else [Column1] ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replaced Value",{"Previous Row"})  
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to PBI, how do I do this in the Power Query Editor?

Comment: Added a new method with step by step from the user interface

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, however it doesn't quite do what I'm looking for. I can attach my advanced editor + what it looks like on my end!

Comment: Added an update!

Comment: What is the before/after picture looking like now? Is it doing anything? Any error generated. What is it doing, if anything, which is not what you want

Comment: I attached the after photo on the post!

Column 1 had

357
355
359
329

but after pasting it, 359 and 329 got transferred to Column 2 and 339 was the one pasted in both.

in shiftedList, the returned list is

357
355
null 
null

Comment: It was a mistake on my end, it works great! I realized I had removed my test data